# How do you centre text in a multicolumn table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I used the following code below to create a multicolumn table. I want to centre 'THIS'. How does one go about it? (I'm quite new to Latex and I got this from a thesis template from uni so I'm unsure how to do it)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption[Table1]{How do I center 'THIS' above the midrule}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}} \toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{THIS}} \\ \cmidrule(){2-5}
    \textbf{Object} 
    &
    \textbf{1} 
    &
    \textbf{2} 
    &
    \textbf{3} 
    &
    \textbf{4}
    \\
    \midrule
    Aa & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
    \\[0.3ex]
    Bb & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
    \\[0.3ex]
    \bottomrule
    \label{table:Table1}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can put an empty cell before the `\multicolumn` (using `& \multicolumn`) and let the multicolumn span the other four columns.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! @Marijn